# Adobe Flash update breaks Opera Plugin due to file name change

Tags: windows, opera, flash-player

I keep my Opera browser open for many days.  But after some time the Adobe Flash PPAPI plugin stops working and only restarting the browser seemed to help.  Killing the plugin in the Opera task manager does not help.

**I have identified the cause of this problem:**

- Adobe Flash automatically updates itself and in this process changes the dll filename eg. from `pepflashplayer32_19_0_0_157.dll` to `pepflashplayer32_19_0_0_162.dll`.  The old .dll is deleted
- Opera still lists the old .dll on its `about://plugins` page
- Copying the new dll to the old filename and killing the the flash player plugin task solves the problem without restarting Opera

**My question:**

- Is there a way to have Adboe Flash offer its .dll through a constant name eg. a link to the current filename?
- Or can Opera rescan the plugins locations without restarting the browser?
- Or is there another way/service that automatically updates Adobe Flash but does not create this problem. I do not want to switch the update service to notify-only.

Answer (score 0):

Use a symbolic link to keep the name constant. Here is the syntax:

```
PS C:\> new-item -itemtype symboliclink -path <path to location> -value <path to target>
```

For example:

```
PS C:\> new-item -itemtype symboliclink -path $env:PROGRAMFILES\pepflashplayer32_19_0_0_157.dll -value $env:PROGRAMFILES\pepflashplayer32_19_0_0_162.dll
```

**References**

- [Interact with Symbolic links using improved Item cmdlets | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/feedback_symbolic)